# QGIS 3.22 vertex editor snapping placing vertices in wrong location

Tags: qgis, vertices

I've been having a strange issue with my vertex editor over the past couple of days. I am attempting to edit a polygon such that the borders of the polygon line up with a different line segment layer on my map. I have snapping enabled to any line segment for that layer, so I can snap the vertices of the polygon to the line I'm trying to match them to.

Most of the time, this works perfectly fine. I place the vertex and it goes where it's supposed to. But sometimes, the vertex goes somewhere totally different than indicated. I hover my mouse over the magenta indicator for snapping, click it, and the vertex "bounces" over to a totally different area! I have no idea where to even begin on solving this issue, it's unlike anything I've ever seen from a GIS.

The screenshot below is the best illustration I can provide. I clicked on a snap point on one of the yellow lines, and the vertex in the bottom left is where it placed instead.

My snapping tolerance is 11px, if that's relevant.

[image]

Comment: Did you check for geometry/topology errors? Can you try it with the same data, but using another QGIS version and using a new, clean user profile: does the problem persist?

Comment: Perhaps there is no vertex on the lower-most yellow line within the screenshot , but there is a vertex on some unidentified layer at the position marked.

Comment: @Babel Yes, the problem persists, and it seems to occur at random: on some startups, the snapping works fine, and then later after a full shutdown and restart, the problem starts up again, and sometimes only occurs a handful of times while all other instances work fine.